# Windows 8 App - LINQ search results

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to search a SQLITE DB by using a text box as a search parameter, here is what I have so far:

```
 private async void search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hdw.sqlite");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
            {
                //var d = from x in db.Table<Customers>() select x;
                //var custSearchQuery = db.Table<Customers>().Where(x => x.customerName == TBSearch.Text);

                string search = TBSearch.Text;
                var custSearchQuery = from x in db.Table<Customers>()
                                      where search.Contains(x.customerName)
                                      select x;

                customerList.Items.Clear();

                //customerList.ItemsSource = db.Table<Customers>();


                foreach (var sd in custSearchQuery)
                {

                    customerList.Items.Add(sd.customerNumber.ToString());

                }

                db.Dispose();
                db.Close();
            }


        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I am trying to return all results that the TBSearch value is within the customerName field.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: You should not have an empty catch block there.

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispose()` and `Close()` inside of a `using` block?

Comment: @Servy I want to return my search results to a list view. Search for Black in textbox, return all results that contain Black in the database field, customerName.

Comment: @GarlingBeard That's still not a question.

Comment: @Servy Ok how can I return the results of a text box search using the above format to a my list view? How would I update my LINQ query?

Comment: @GarlingBeard In what way is your code currently not doing that?  What problems does it have?

Comment: @Servy Right now I need to search for an exact name, for example 'chickasaw farm service' returns one result but when I search for 'chickasaw' no results show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now:

```
 string search = TBSearch.Text;

                var custSearchQuery = from c in db.Table<Customers>()
                                      where c.customerName.Contains(search)
                                      select c;
```